# Resultado de un campo en varios sql server

Tags: sql, servidor

Como genero una consulta que me de resultados asi:

```
Nombre               nombre_sigue
David Lopez          danilo cruz
Carlos perez         sebastian corea
Juana maria          maria dinora
Patricia aguilar     kurt heiz
```

en este ejemplo son 10 nombre en una tabla de empleados con un campo nombre. Yo no quiero que me muestre en un solo campo el resultado, sino en dos del 1 al 5 en una columna y del 6 al 10 en otra. alguna idea? subconsultas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una alternativa que básicamente divide un conjunto de filas en dos columnas, permite también que la cantidad sea impar.

```
DECLARE @Personas TABLE (
    Nombre VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @Personas (Nombre)
SELECT  'David Lopez'       UNION 
SELECT  'danilo cruz'       UNION 
SELECT  'Carlos perez'      UNION          
SELECT  'sebastian corea'   UNION 
SELECT  'Juana maria'       UNION 
SELECT  'maria dinora'      UNION 
SELECT  'Patricia aguilar'  UNION 
SELECT  'kurt heiz'     UNION 
SELECT  'Luis Perez'    

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  Nombre,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Nombre) AS RN,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @Personas) AS CT
        FROM @Personas
)
SELECT  T1.Nombre,
    T2.Nombre
    FROM CTE T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2
        ON T2.rn = T1.RN + CEILING(T1.CT/2.0) 
    WHERE T1.RN <= CEILING(T1.CT/2.0)
```

Salida:

```
+--------------+------------------+
| Carlos perez | Luis Perez       |
+--------------+------------------+
| danilo cruz  | maria dinora     |
+--------------+------------------+
| David Lopez  | Patricia aguilar |
+--------------+------------------+
| Juana maria  | sebastian corea  |
+--------------+------------------+
| kurt heiz    | NULL             |
+--------------+------------------+
```

Explicación:

- Primero que nada creo una tabla temporal `@Personas` con los datos que diste, más un caso adicional para hacer la lista impar y probar el funcionamiento en estos casos
- Luego usamos un CTE de forma recursiva para hacer `JOIN` entre los registros del lado izquierdo y el derecho

Answer (score 1):

Si tu tabla tiene una estructura como la siguiente:

**Tabla1**

- id (pk) (numeric)
- nombres (varchar)

Lo que se me ocurre es lo siguiente con una subconsulta.

```
SELECT Top(10) A.nombres AS 'Nombre', (SELECT B.nombres
    FROM Tabla1 AS B
    WHERE B.id = (A.id + 10)) AS 'nombre_sigue'
FROM Tabla1 AS A
ORDER BY A.id
```

Con ello logras los siguiente:

- Con el **Top** solo obtienes los 10 primeros resultados
- Con la subconsulta el nombre que se encuentre 10 posiciones al que esta en la primera columna

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo rostan, pero en este caso quien es B?

Comment: Disculpa, olvidé agregar el FROM en la subconsulta; sería la misma tabla. Saludos.

Comment: Genial eres un campeón, te agradezco ya lo probé y es justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: De nada, no olvides dar por resulta tu pregunta con esta respuesta. Fue un gusto.