# Como anidar 'select' independientes?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente tabla con informacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito mostrar es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo intento con este codigo, pero me duplica los datos:

```
               SELECT * FROM

                  (SELECT Codigo AS LYC 
                  FROM RequerimientoDetalle
                  WHERE Codigo like '%LYC%') t1,

                  (SELECT Codigo AS MYE 
                  FROM RequerimientoDetalle
                  WHERE Codigo like '%MYE%') t2
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es si existe alguna función para motor mysql o sqlserver,
para poder realizar de forma exitosa esta query.

También intente agruparlos y el resultado es el mismo.

Tomar en cuenta que la tabla crece, MyE-3..5,6,7.etc o LyC-3..5,6,7.etc

Comment: Hola, me temo que lo que preguntas no es posible, a menos que el numero de elementos en la tabla _MyE_ sea igual al numero de _LyC_, la consulta no se puede generar, ya que una de las columnas sera mas grande que la otra. Te recomendaría hacer las consultas por separado.

Comment: Por qué necesitas que la data se muestre en ese formato?? De ser posible edita la pregunta y detalla a que se debe. Por otro lado, hace tiempo ayudé a otro usuario con una pregunta parecida a la tuya, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150999/resultado-de-un-campo-en-varios-sql-server/151007?noredirect=1#comment282988_151007, revisala y cuentanos.

Comment: @the-breaker exactamente es el problema que me pasa actualmente.

Comment: @Rostan mañana lo reviso y te comento.lo que tengo son 2 select de una misma columna, ambos si los ejecutó por separados cumplen, pero e problema es cuando necesito anidarlos en 1 solo query. No se me ocurre otra pregunta.

Comment: Rostan  lo que respondes es prácticamente lo mismo que tengo yo, pero limitado, lo cual no me sirve debido a que como indica @the-breaker una columna puede tener mas datos de los que mostrara la segunda columna y esto creara duplicidad de datos (que es lo que me pasa actualmente). se me asemeja mas la solución que da Patricio-Moracho talves con una tabla temporal con WITH CTE podría ser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es: con esas 2 tablas que obtuviste, generar un    `FULL OUTER JOIN` 
 por una enumeración dinámica en el `select`.
Crearías una columna enumerada, en cada `select` y luego hacer el `join` sobre esa columna.

> Puedes probarlo aqui https://sqltest.net/#261921

```
 SELECT TLYC.codigo as LYC, TMYE.codigo as MYE FROM (SELECT codigo,row_num FROM 
    (
    SELECT T1.codigo ,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as row_num
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT codigo
        FROM mysql_test
        WHERE codigo like 'LYC-%') T1
    , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
    ) TLYC_IN ) TLYC
LEFT JOIN
   (
   SELECT codigo,row_num FROM 
    (
    SELECT T2.codigo ,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as row_num
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT codigo
        FROM mysql_test
        WHERE codigo like 'MYE-%') T2
    , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r2
    ) TMYE_IN) TMYE ON TLYC.row_num = TMYE.row_num
UNION
SELECT TLYC.codigo as LYC, TMYE.codigo as MYE FROM (SELECT codigo,row_num FROM 
    (
    SELECT T1.codigo ,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as row_num
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT codigo
        FROM mysql_test
        WHERE codigo like 'LYC-%') T1
    , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
    ) TLYC_IN ) TLYC
RIGHT  JOIN
   (
   SELECT codigo,row_num FROM 
    (
    SELECT T2.codigo ,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as row_num
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT codigo
        FROM mysql_test
        WHERE codigo like 'MYE-%') T2
    , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r2
    ) TMYE_IN) TMYE ON TLYC.row_num = TMYE.row_num
```

Nota: se cambia `full outer join` por `UNION` con `LEFT` y `RIGHT JOIN`

Inserts

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81486/discussion-on-answer-by-luciano-montanez-como-anidar-select-independientes).